# R - summary statistics of non-null elements of dataframe

Tags: r, null, mean, na

I have a dataframe column (of type factor) in a dataframe df that looks like:

```
var1
0.25
0.35
NULL
0
-0.15
NULL
NULL
0.50
```

when I try to use the following command:

```
mean(df$var1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

I get

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(df$var1, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

How can I get the summary statistics excluding the "NULL" values?

Comment: Convert to numeric first. `mean(as.numeric(as.character(df$var1)), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: No need, this post is a duplicate, I am trying to find the link.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26476652/680068

Comment: Should I delete this thread then?

Comment: Please do not delete, duplicated posts are **useful** for searching similar problems that are worded in different ways.

Comment: why don't you post your answer so that I can accept it then

Comment: @RonakShah added as wiki, and closed as dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to numeric first:

```
mean(as.numeric(as.character(df$var1)), na.rm = TRUE)
```